# How to multiply fields in Django ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to multiply the price and quantity fields from my modelForm to create a total_value field.  I would like the value to populate after the user inputs a value for price and quantity.  I have tried creating functions in the model to carry out the multiplication, however, I do not understand how to post the data in the template.  Sorry I am very new to programming.  Below are the links to my code.

[forms.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LtzO.png)

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y043C.png)

[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erF8O.png)

[template.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R3F9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the function calc_total, just use that function instead of total_value. It will work just fine,

like this

{{ item.calc_total }}

Comment: That is a little embarrassing.  Thank-you!  Worked like a charm.  :)